# Title and Axis labels

Tags: label, d3.js, axis, title

I have been successful in creating labels for both the X and Y axis. I have also been successful in adding a title to the graph. My problem is that if I modify the margins of the graph, the label positions get messed up.

**Snippet of where I change the margins of the graph:**

```
    var margin = {top: 60, right: 60, bottom: 60, left:120}
```

**Snippet of where I create the labels:**

```
    //Create Title 
    svg.append("text")
    .attr("x", w / 2 )
    .attr("y", 0)
    .style("text-anchor", "middle")
    .text("Title of Diagram");

    //Create X axis label   
    svg.append("text")
    .attr("x", w / 2 )
    .attr("y",  h + margin.bottom)
    .style("text-anchor", "middle")
    .text("State");

    //Create Y axis label
    svg.append("text")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
    .attr("y", 0-margin.left)
    .attr("x",0 - (h / 2))
    .attr("dy", "1em")
    .style("text-anchor", "middle")
    .text("Revenue");
```

**JsFiddle:**
http://jsfiddle.net/u63T9/

**Here is another alternative, that I'm willing to live with:**
I am basically leveraging the scales to find a base coordinate. I then add or take a little until I am happy with the location. This method actually keeps up with changes in the margins.

```
    //Create title 
    svg.append("text")
    .attr("x", w / 2 )
    .attr("y",  yScale(d3.max(input, function(d) { return d.CustomerCount; })) - 20 )
    .style("text-anchor", "middle")
    .text("Title of Graph");

    //Create X axis label   
    svg.append("text")
    .attr("x", w / 2 )
    .attr("y",  yScale(0) + 40 )
    .style("text-anchor", "middle")
    .text("State");

    //Create Y axis label
    svg.append("text")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
    .attr("y", xScale(0) - 80 )
    .attr("x",0 - (h / 2))
    .attr("dy", "1em")
    .style("text-anchor", "middle")
    .text("Revenue");
```

Comment: There's not really anything you can do about it except compute the space the labels will need and make sure that the margins are at least that large.

Comment: Solution here http://www.d3noob.org/2012/12/adding-axis-labels-to-d3js-graph.html. You can download the complete PDF 'D3 Tips and Tricks' for free here: https://leanpub.com/D3-Tips-and-Tricks.

Answer (score 12):

I use a simple function to measure text and then compute margins based on that.

```
// create a dummy element, apply the appropriate classes,
// and then measure the element
function measure(text, classname) {
  if(!text || text.length === 0) return {height: 0, width: 0};

  var container = d3.select('body').append('svg').attr('class', classname);
  container.append('text').attr({x: -1000, y: -1000}).text(text);

  var bbox = container.node().getBBox();
  container.remove();

  return {height: bbox.height, width: bbox.width};
}
```

Now you can use

```
var titleSize = measure('my title', 'chart title'),
    margin.top = titleSize.height + 20; // add whatever padding you want
```

I updated your example at http://jsfiddle.net/uzddx/2/.  You can see the top margin resizes when you modify the font size of the title.  You could do something similar for the left margin so that your label isn't so far away from the y-axis.

Comment: Thanks Bill, but I am new to D3 and I couldn't completely follow your solution.

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with D3, I'm just using `getBBox` in SVG to measure text.  Once you have the height of the text string, you can modify your margins so that they fit correctly. In other words, don't hard code your margins, measure the labels and set your margins based on their size.

Comment: I have tried with d3 and found issue on installing jsdom and then followed 
http://www.steveworkman.com/node-js/2012/installing-jsdom-on-windows/ but still hard luck. Instead there is https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio .it's the alternative to jsdom. So any way to work with cherrio,d3,d3-measure-text. My ultimate goal is to achieve the text-dimensions that we are getting on graphics.Measurestring in c#. Pls note that npm-canvas is not an option as it require chiro and hard with windows installment. Pls save me. I have already taken so much time.